# Extension method which this of type "Type" is null

Tags: c#, .net

I created an extension method for System.Type and I would like to unit test that method. Is this possible? Thanks!

```
public static bool GetFoo(this Type self)
{
     if (self == null)
     {
          throw new ArgumentNullException("this")
     }
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assert that `((Type)null).GetFoo()` throws.

Comment: @Maarten: I haven't been to a shootout in a long time.  Not sure if I still had it, with all my time in the saloon...

Answer (score 4):

MS VS Unit Test

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
public void TestFoo()
{
    Type t = null;
    t.GetFoo();
}
```

Comment: Works as well! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this too:

```
ExtensionClass.GetFoo(null)
```

Edit: Just noted this is the same as Jason Evans's now deleted answer...

Answer (score 0):

Just extending with other ways:

```
        this.GetType().GetFoo();//inside some class.
        typeof(SomeType).GetFoo();
```

Since it throws an ArgumentNullException you can wrap it inside a proper try-catch block